# orfeo tool box Optical calibration

Tags: otb-applications

I am trying to customize Optical calibration module for hyperion sensor. I am not able to find RSR foramt .can any one suggest me what is the format of Relative Spectral Response File which is on of the input to Optical calibration module.I followed the link https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_OpticalCalibration.html#authors